# Google Sheets: Parsing users who are Program Managers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet that is always updating with 50+ rows. I am trying to retrieve users who are Program Managers (PGM) by parsing text but I am having a hard time since the data is not consistent since it's filled out by 20+ users.

I googled "google sheet parse text" but it's giving me functions such as =SEARCH, =LENS, =LEFT which I cannot use since my data is not consistent. Are there any other options or am I out of luck and must parse my info manually? Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot Example]

[Google Sheet Link Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KOD3xsgG3khFn8jAzPNDU2wZjT8bimZbXjdLfoTjitM/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `C2` use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"PGM:.*")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=byrow(B2:B,lambda(z,if(z="",,ifna(regexextract(z,"(PGM:.*)(?:\n|$)")))))
```

- row 6 outcome is varying a bit

[image]